# How to split file name in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, logstash, kibana, logstash-file

I am injecting a file from the s3 bucket to logstash, My file name is containing some information, I want to split the file name into multiple fields, so I can use them as separate fields. Please help me I am new with elk.

```
input {
 s3 {
    bucket => "***********"
    access_key_id => "***********"
    secret_access_key => "*******"
    "region" => "*********"
    
    "prefix" => "Logs"
    "interval" => "1"
    "additional_settings" => {
           "force_path_style" => true
           "follow_redirects" => false
           }
    }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => {
      "file" => "%{[@metadata][s3][key]}"              //This file name have to split
    }
   
  }
}

output {
 elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  index => "indexforlogstash"
     
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample file name (even redacted), it's just to see what kind of pattern we're talking about

Comment: @Val file
Logs/1232131-custombuildv12-log.txt this is my file where Logs is prefix and remaining is the filename,  numeric value represent some device id and custombuildv12 represent build id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `filter` section you can leverage the [`dissect` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html) in order to achieve what you want:

```
filter {
    ...

    dissect {
      mapping => {
        "file" => "Logs/%{deviceId}-%{buildId}-log.txt"
      }
    }
}
```

After going through this filter, your document is going to get two new fields, namely:

- `deviceId` (1232131)
- `buildId` (custombuildv12)

Comment: Thanks, you saved me

Comment: Newley added fields are not searchable even after refreshing (Stack management then index management)  Do you have any idea?

Comment: Have you refreshed your index pattern in Stack management > Index patterns?

Comment: Ok got it, actually, I was refreshing index management, Now its working fine. Big thanks